# How to properly test actor behavior in case of failure

Tags: scala, akka, akka-testkit

It is very important to know how a system might behave in case a particular actor fails - how does the recovery run, are the snapshots fetched properly etc. Surprisingly, I have not found any advice on it in [the docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html)

An approach I have seen in some examples is to have a special `Fail` msg and let the actor throw an `Exception` on this msg.

```
class MyActor extends Actor {
  override def receive =
    ...
    case Fail => throw new Exception("kaboom")
}
```

I hope never to use it as it mixes production code and test code and would probably generate some reasonable WTFs in unsuspecting readers.

How would I induce an arbitrary actor to fail properly?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

After some thought, I have implemented a quick solution. The test package contains a trait for failing which is then mixed into actors for failure testing:

```
object Failing{
  case object Fail
}

trait Failing {
  def failOnMsg: PartialFunction[Any, Unit] = {
    case Fail => throw new Exception("kaboom!")
  }
}
```

then in the test the PF is prepended to the original `receive`

```
val props = Props(new MyActor(arg) with Failing {
  override def receive = failOnMsg orElse super.receive
})

val actor = system.actorOf(props)
actor ! Fail
```

It is still better than what I had before, but brings some boilerplate. I hope there is a better solution.